# Recommendations on how to do eight directional movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to make eight directional movement in my game.

I was successful of doing the movement using `rigidBody2D` but it wasn't as snappy as I expected. I looked at the scripting API and there looks like alot of ways of moving things around so it's abit intimidating for a noobie like me ;^;. I tried translating but it seems that I didn't put in the right arguments since the player character didn't move(It did compile perfectly fine)

Even though my previous way of moving the character with the rigid body was fine I need snappy tight movement since the game is gonna be a bullet hell similar to Touhou so the smooth velocity based movement won't work well unless I was making a rage game(which I'm not). 
I'm thinking that the solution for it is to use position based movement but the API makes finding things abit intimidating.

Edit: Here's the code that wasn't snappy but did make the character move around in eight directions

```
 moveX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed;
 moveY = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;

 movement = new Vector2(moveX, moveY);
 rb.velocity = movement;
```

This is all inside of the update function.

Comment: Did you attempt setting the rigidbody2d.position directly?

Comment: You can use `RigidBody2D` to make snappy movement. Please share the code that was not snappy so that we can help you fix it.

Comment: @Eddge I attempted rigidbody2d.position but once I let go of the keys the character will go back to it's original place

Comment: @AlanNoobmaker is  that because you are setting it rather then adding it?  so `rigidbody2d.position = rigidbody2d.position + direction * time.fixeddeltatime;`

Comment: @Eddge K then how do I declare direction? do I use the `Input.GetAxis` stuff or is it something else? Edit: I tried `rb.position = rb.position + moveX *time.fixeddeltatime` so yeah that way won't work

Comment: @AlanNoobmaker I would recommend looking up a tutorial on Unity.  That is a very basic question.